# Wordpress Contact form 7 falat error while send an email

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_status() on null in /home/mywebsite/public_html/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/contact-form.php:732 
Stack trace: 
#0 /home/mywebsite/public_html/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/controller.php(14): WPCF7_ContactForm->submit() 
#1 /home/mywebsite/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(285): wpcf7_control_init()
#2 /home/mywebsite/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) 
#3 /home/mywebsite/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(544): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) 
#4 /home/mywebsite/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php(388): do_action_ref_array('parse_request', Array)
#5 /home/mywebsite/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php(739): WP->parse_request('') 
#6 /home/mywebsite/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php(1274): WP->main('') 
#7 /home/mywebsite/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(16): wp() 
#8 /home/mywebsite/public_html/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/contact-form.php on line 732
```

There has been a critical error on your website.

Learn more about debugging in WordPress.

While submit contact form mail is recived but fatal error appear.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: New version : 5.2

Comment: Are you using any other contact form 7 plugins, or have you hooked into anything that gets the submissions?

Comment: I have deactive all plugins

Comment: Its custom theme and printed using do_shortcode

Comment: My guess is that somewhere in the custom theme, there is a function that is calling the class `WPCF7_Submission` ?  If there is... can you share that function?

Comment: There is no such function

Comment: Based on what you're saying, the form submission is returning a null, so if you're saying that there are no other cf7 plugins, and nothing special in the additional settings tab, then you have some kind of bug that you should try reporting to the developer. Although he's not very helpful.

Comment: can you debug for me

Comment: I will share theme

Comment: If it's a free theme, I'd take a look.  Otherwise, I'd advise searching for `WPCF7_Submission` in your theme files, and this is probably the source of the error.

Comment: I will debug its custom theme. Its hard to find a issue

Comment: My advice is to download the entire theme to your local computer.  Open it in something like Atom. Search for `WPCF7_Submission` post the function that uses it.

Comment: I  have change my mind create custom form instead this.

Answer (score 0):

At the same position as I state in my answer, inside the plugin itself:

/public/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/contact-form.php
Line 732

You’ll see the lines I commented out in my answer are those at line 732.

This is a hotfix and should be checked with after each update of the plugin.

Comment: are you have plugin Autoptimize ?

Comment: This is a poor answer. The cf7 plugin is not the issue here. Something else is causing this.

Comment: CF7 is not an issue. Its working fine with all other theme.

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case, disabling  "Wordfence" plugin, then disabling "
Wordpress 2-Step Verification"  plugin, then re-enabling Wordfence plugin, solved the problem.